# Class not found with Guzzle Http Client

Tags: php, autoload

This is a strange error that's constantly occurring.

> Fatal error: Class 'Guzzle\Http\Client' not found in /home/futcoins/public_html/autobuyer/classes/shopify.php on line 15

This is the source code. I think this question is pretty straight forward and I've been stuck with this problem for a couple of days, any ideas?

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookiePlugin;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookieJar\FileCookieJar;

class Shopify {

        //initialise the class
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function GetOrders() {       

        $client = new Client(null); //Line 15 where errors occurs
        $request = $client->get("url"); 
        $response = $request->send();
        $json = $response->json();
        return $json;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to `include` the file in which `Guzzle\Http\Client` is defined, a `use` directive doesn't do that on its own. Have you configured autoloaders or do you have any other strategy for including files...?

Comment: @deceze No. I have not configured the autoloaders as I don't know how that works. Could you explain?

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: @deceze This did not solve my problem. It works on localhost like this.

Comment: *How* are you including your files exactly? They're not being included by magic.

Comment: @deceze If I knew the answer to that question then I wouldn't need anyone's help...

Comment: If it works on your localhost you must have *something* set up. Are you using a framework? Or Composer maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a declaration at the top

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
```

That means you either have an autoloader or have included the appropriate file(s) manually. So you need to find the file that has that class and include it or else PHP will be looking for code you've not given to it.

Comment: It works completely fine on my localhost I don't see why it's not working on my online server. This didn't help me.

Comment: @Corona then you installed Guzzle in some way on your localhost, but not on your remote machine. Please not that without eplicit `include` or `require` statements, PHP will not load any code by itself. If you are using *Composer*, I recommend you follow the steps in the [ReadMe](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is the right solution for you but I had the exact same problem and to fix it I updated composer on my server and regenerated the autoload file:

```
sudo /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update
/usr/bin/composer.phar dump-autoload
```

I'm not sure it is necessary but I also restarted apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

To prevent this in the future and because we are using Elastic Beanstalk I created an configuration file to make sure that composer is up to date:

```
commands:
  01updateComposer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
```

Source: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx2M04LCN1UEE0E/Reduce-Composer-Issues-on-Elastic-Beanstalk